# Manupluating dataframes in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have a dataframe that looks as below-

```
import pandas as pd

filename = r"/home/EVENTS.S001.R001"

# This returns a dataframe with a single column
df = pd.read_table(filename, header=None)
df = df[0].str.split("  ", expand=True)

df
```

```
0       2.0     0       5       6.31000     None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None
1               5.60196         2.98423         2.21817         0.04454         0.00000     None    None    None    None    None    None
2       2.0     0       5       6.31000     None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None
3               5.23222         0.87787         0.67289         0.04454         0.00000     None    None    None    None    None    None
4       2.0     0       4       6.31000     None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None
...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
200024              3.92921         1.01950         0.04454         0.00000     None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None
200025      2.0     0       3       6.31000     None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None
200026              3.70093         1.50100         0.00000     None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None
200027      2.0     0       3       6.31000     None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None
200028              4.35257         1.63800         0.00000     None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None
```

I am trying to sort it according to the value in the 4th column of every row that begins with 2.0. For example in the first row, this value is 5

I want to store all the values below the rows wherever this value is 5 and make a different dataframe with those values.

For example here is what I am expecting the dataframe for value = 5 at the position in the 4th column of every row that begins with 2.0 -

```
 5.60196 2.98423 2.21817 0.04454
 5.23222 0.87787 0.67289 0.04454 0.00000
```

and so on…

I want to make mini-dataframes out of this big one for different values starting from 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 at this position in the fourth column.

Can someone show me if there is a way to do this?

I attach my datafile- https://www.swisstransfer.com/d/6b9d6ebb-64cc-4868-b570-b6d448b87ddd

Comment: People don't want to look at an image or download a data file.  Instead, create a copyable toy example that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: What is the format of your file? Specifically, how are the columns delimited? I think having a single-column dataframe is preventing you from doing what you want. If you can import the data into a dataframe *with* the columns separate and intact, then there are lots of well documented, easy ways of doing what you want to do.